# How does this recursion work in python?

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x, palindrome

I watched a video a couple of hours ago on recursion in python and then recreated the program which was made in the video so it worked in my version of Python. The code works but there is a bit I don't understand fully and what it is doing.

```
def lower(s):
    s = s.lower()
    return s

def isPal(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])

def isPalindrome(s):
    if isPal(lower(s)) == True:
        print("{0} is a palindrome".format(s))
```

The part which I am having an issue with is the

```
return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])
```

What I am wondering is why are they being returned and also why is it s[1:-1] and not s[0:-1] if you think you know of any good places which would help simplify recursions for me feel free to share them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best way to figure out recursion is to take a piece of paper and pen and trace out what the program is doing, line by line. Keep a track of your stack and the layers of recursion that get added onto it. Use an applicable example to your situation- for example, pretend that the input to this algorithm is "racecar"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why is it s[1:-1] and not s[0:-1]

`s[1:-1]` returns `s` with the first and last element chopped off. `s[0:-1]` returns `s` with just the last element chopped off.

You need to chop off both ends to preserve the palindrome property (if it is a palindrome), which is that elements equidistant from the middle are identical. If you chop off only one end, you move the middle, which would (in the general case) destroy that invariant.

This goes to the heart of self recursion: you do a thing, then you delegate a simpler case which has the same properties.

> Why return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])

This is being returned because it first checks that the first and last elements have the palindrome property (as above) AND that the next "layer" also has that property. If the outer pair is not equal it is not a palindrome, and `False` will be returned; if it is true, the recursive step is taken, and if that is True, the expression as a whole returns `True`.

Comment: Thanks, this clears things up, I was forgetting that the s[1:-1] does not include this last char.

Comment: @Marcin I didn't realize Python stopped recursive calls and returned Boolean depending on the operator and possible results, such as once it saw the False, it stopped and return False since the `and` operator was used, I guess. I see now that it does it with `or` as well, as soon as it sees True, it returns True, that is. Do you know of any documentation on this or others? I noticed it doesn't do it with multiplication of 0. Thx.

Comment: @MakeCents It doesn't "stop recursive calls". Short-circuiting is a property of the `and` operator, and is extremely common, being present in one form or another in almost all programming languages. The python behaviour is documented in the language specifications under the "Operators" sections.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you have the word *'kayak'*

The program will look if :

`'k' == 'k'` if yes the program will call the function with : `'aya'`

Then the program will look if `'a' == 'a'` if yes the program will call the function with `'y'`

Then it's only one letter, So the program returns `True`

Answer (score 3):

This is where the magic happens:

```
return (s[0] == s[-1]) and isPal(s[1:-1])
```

(I have added parentheses, so you are absolutely clear on the operator precedence). It is important to know that the Python AND statement will evaluate the first argument, and only if it is `True`, will it evaluate the second argument. If the first was `False`, then it will return `False` immediately without calling `isPal()`. This is known as [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). [Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18898515/341459) makes a good example of this in his post.

`s[0]` is the first letter in the string, `s[-1]` is the last letter in the sting. First we check to see if the first and last letters are the same. If they are different, then there is no way the string can be a palindrome. If the are the same we can disregard them and move onto the inner part of the string.

`s[1:-1]` trims off the first and last letters, and then passes that to the `isPal()` function, which happens to be the function we are currently in -- this is called recursion. When we 'recurse' into the function again, a new stack is created, new local variables are created, and the input arguments to the function will be different to the ones in the previous call.

We continue to check the first and last letters, and recurse all the way to the centre of the word. At this point there are either 1 or 0 characters left, and if we have got that far we know we have found a palindrome.

When we return from this final, inner, call to `isPal()` the return value (`True` if a palindrome has been found) is passed to the calling function, which then returns it to its calling function, etc., until the final 'outside' `isPal()` function returns the result to the initial caller. We call this process 'unrolling the stack'.

Here is an example:

```
s = 'racecar'
s[0] == s[-1] # True - both letters are 'r'
s = s[1:-1]   # s becomes 'aceca'
s[0] == s[-1] # True - both letters are 'a'
s = s[1:-1]   # s becomes 'cec'
s[0] == s[-1] # True - both letters are 'c'
s = s[1:-1]   # s becomes 'e'
len(s) <= 1   # This statement is now True, so the stack will start to unwind
```

Visually, the calls will look like this:

```
'racecar' ---------
                  |
                  V    'aceca'
 True <--- isPal(   ) ----
             ^           |
        True |           V     'cec'
             ---- isPal(   ) ----
                    ^           |
               True |           V     'e'
                    ---- isPal(   ) ----
                           ^           |
                      True |           V
                           ---- isPal(   )  # We get all the way down here,
                                            # and then we start to return
```

In the case where we do not have a palindrome, this will happen:

```
'race2car' --------
                  |
                  V    'ace2ca'
False <--- isPal(   ) ----
             ^           |
       False |           V     'ce2c'
             ---- isPal(   ) ----
                    ^           |
              False |           V     'e2'
                    ---- isPal(   ) ----
                           ^           |
                     False |           V
                           ---- isPal(   )  # Here the outer two letters
                                            # do not match, so we start to
                                            # return False
```

Comment: Nice diagrams! Done by hand, or is there a tool?

Comment: @LeeNetherton I too loved your visuals, but, shouldn't the last one be True up until it gets to 'e2'? Then True and False are False?

Comment: @MakeCents: No, nothing will start to be returned until the final `isPal()` returns False. At that point, all of the previous function calls will effectively pass this return value back up the stack. So they will all return the same value.

Comment: @LeeNetherton Oh okay, thanks. The way recursive unwinds still messes with my head sometimes.

Comment: It still feels to me that it should be True `and` False `and` True `and` True, which would be False, recursively. One day I might get this.

Comment: I see what you are getting at now. The values that I put on the diagram are the return values only, I do not include any of the 'internal' values that are evaluated in the `and` statements, which would include some `True` values of course.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if the first and last of `s` are the same, so once you do that you slice them off and check if the next first and last are the same by returning, the recursive part, and it keeps adding together the result until there is 1 or less letters in s. It then returns what you have gathered so far and True.

Adding a `print(s)` on the line before `if len(s) <= 1:` or a `print(s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1]))` after the `else:` may help you understand the recursion more.

Answer (score 0):

That step uses the short-circuiting logical AND, so it really acts like this:

```
if s[0] != s[-1]:
    return False
else:
    return isPal(s[1:-1])
```

As for `s[1:-1]`, you compare the first and last characters with `s[0] != s[-1]`, so `s[1:-1]` just removes the first and last characters and passes the resulting string back into `isPal`.